# symfony2 customize form datetime rendering

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime, templates, twig

I have a form with a datetime rendered as 5 select inputs d MM YYYY H-i

```
$builder
        ->add('date', 'datetime',
            array(
                'data' => new \DateTime('now'), //default value
                'format' => 'd-MM-yyyy H-i-s',
                'years' => array(2016, 2017),
            )
        )
        ->getForm();
```

[image]

I would like to customize the template and hide the character ":" between the minutes and seconds select inputs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
The datetime field can be rendered as more select inputs in twig template like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.date.date.day) }}
{{ form_widget(form.date.date.month) }}
{{ form_widget(form.date.date.year) }}
{{ form_widget(form.date.time.hour) }}
{{ form_widget(form.date.time.minute) }}
```