# How to render individual fields from DateTimeType?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

How to render individual fields from DateTimeType?

```
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.year) }}
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.month) }}
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.day) }}
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.hour) }}
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.minute) }}
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.second) }}
```

Didn't work.

Or how can I have it in separate fields in the view, but in the database and Entity in one?

Comment: It's described in the [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419357/symfony2-customize-form-datetime-rendering